# Laravel viaRemember always returning false

Tags: php, laravel

I've had trouble with keeping my users logged in, so I did some testing and I noticed that the function viaRemember always returns `false`.

This is my login controller function with all the irrelevant code stripped off:

```
public function postSignin(Request $request, AppMailer $mailer) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);     

    $username = $request->get('email');
    $password = $request->get('password');

    $field = filter_var($username,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)? 'email': 'username';      

    Auth::attempt([$field => $username, 'password' => $password], true);


    return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'You are now signed in.');
}
```

Works fine. As you can see the 2nd argument in `Auth::attempt` is set to `true` by default.

In my database, the value for "remember_token" is changed at every login, so that appears to be working. However, if I do  `dd(Auth::viaRemember());` the result will always be `false`.

I tried changing my `config/session.php` settings as well, switching some values around, but that doesn't seem to do much.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood this feature. "viaRemember" is to check whether the returning user is authenticated via "remember me" function.
Definitely the first time you login with "remember me" checked this will return false. Try closing your browser and open up again it will return true.

Or you can do its behavior by going in **config\session.php** and change

```
'expire_on_close' = false
```

to true and everything became fine like you thinking

Comment: Closing and reopening the browser does return true, but only if I have expire_on_close to true. Otherwise it returns false. 

But perhaps I did misunderstand this feature. Specifically, I was testing why I get logged out so quickly on my phone compared to other websites.