# Authentication via remember_token

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-mix, laravel-7

I'm developing an application with Laravel Mix (React). Laravel is providing a remember function (`remember_token`) for login. As I can see in the docs, I can use a separate option for staying logged in (`true` parameter):

```
...
Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password']], true);
...
```

As I wrote, I'm using React for the frontend. So I'm actually doing a `fetch` request to the backend (Laravel) to check if the user is logged in or not. This works fine for the session:

`Auth::check()` returns `true`, if user is logged in, otherwise `false`

but when I use

`Auth::viaRemember()` it always returns `false`, even when I set the option for staying logged in.

Do I need to pass a specific `middleware` to the `route` that this works?
Or do I have to pass the cookie in my `fetch` request, but then, why it works with the session?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49461876/7155723

Comment: Ah ok, so the function `Auth::viaRemember()` is not for authenticating a user, but for checking, if it has been authenticated via remember function. I see. Thanks.

Comment: So it should be sufficient to check the authentication only via `Auth::check()`?

Comment: You only need viaRemember() if you want to do something special for usecases when a user is authenticated via their remember cookie, which should be done in a middleware.